# STL, reducing an array, c++

Tags: c++, stl

For a hw assignment, we are to code a reduce routine that looks like:

```
int reduce(long array[], int size) 
//Where array is the array to reduce, and size is the size of the array.
```

Using STL.  My initial thoughts were to create a set, put all items in the set with a comparison, but then I realized that the set I would create would never be usable since the function returns the size of the new set, but not the set itself to be used.  So I'm not sure how I'd go about using the STL to reduce an array.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Edited:
Sorry, reduce is just to reduce the array into a sorted array without duplicates.

```
E.g. {4, 4, 2, 1} -> {1, 2, 4}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce"?

Comment: Arrays have a constant size, you can not change it. What is reduce? By what criteria?

Comment: Your use of the term 'reduce' should be defined better.  I mean, you could write such a function that has all sorts of "STL" containers in it, but the problem to be solved really is going to drive the decisions.  IMHO it doesn't make sense to [reduce-as-in-map/reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) an array of longs into an int, especially as the operation isn't defined.

Comment: Just to emphasize what other posters have done, the STL isn't just container classes.  It also has algorithms.  An old-style C array is a legitimate container for STL purposes, and pointers into such an array are legitimate random-access iterators, so you can use STL algorithms directly on an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort the array using std::sort, then apply std::unique on it to remove duplicates. std::unique works only on sorted arrays. Just to simplify matters here is how you get `begin` and `end` of a native array:

```
long* begin = array;
long* end   = array + size;
```

Once you have these two things, you can apply standard algorithms easily. Also, if you need to return the new size(used elements in the array):

```
long* end_after_unique = unique(...);
return end_after_unique - array;
```

Answer (score 0):

std::map only allow a single entry and will sort the items for you automatically.  The "second" value in your case is a don't care.

```
std::map<INT32,INT32> mymap;
mymap[i] = array[i];//inserts if not already present
```

Comment: If the key == value, then use std::set, not std::map. You could create this by doing std::set<long> foo(array, array + size);